# Picture processing program, art generator

Tags: image, image-processing

I've found a really amazing wallpaper and later found out that it was a modified version of the original picture (which is an album cover).

Is anyone aware of the program or script being used in order to produce such kind of picture given any input?

Original picture:

[image]

Processed picture:

[image]

Zoom to the processed picture to see the style:

[image]

Is anyone aware of the program or script being used in order to produce such kind of picture given any input?

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of one computer vision area called "Style transfer" using deep neural networks. There is [this famous paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06576.pdf) on this topic.

A few GitHub repos:

1. https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer
2. https://github.com/fzliu/style-transfer
3. https://github.com/anishathalye/neural-style

Answer (score 0):

i would say it can be done eadily by script.  I am building an art generator called the BoredArt Club and using PHP GDlib for image manip.  But if I wanted to use imageMagicK i could do more and it has a windows commandline option.

as for online tools... look at LunaPic and imgonline (UA i think)... they have masking tools and textures, etc   fun stuff

Comment: come to think of it, LunaPic - menu - Art - use ur own style or do Art - davinci and then glow and overlay

Answer (score 0):

I have a bash shell script that uses ImageMagick that will do something similar. See my script, [weave](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick)

Here is an example:

Input:

[image]

Processed:

[image]